# Email body issue

Tags: email, html, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

I have tried to form the email body of a singleemail message as below but it is giving Line break errors. Can someone help me here?

```
 String body = 'Dear ' + OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).Rep_abv__r.Name + ', ';
  body += '<br><br>What you need to know:';
  body += '<br>ABS Incident '+ OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).Name +' has been closed';
  body += '<br>To view your open incidents:<br>';
  body += '<ol type="1">
             <li>       Log into the IREP app on your iPad and select “Compliance Incidents”</li>
             <li>       Select the “Closed Incidents” View in the Compliance Incidents Home Page.</li>
             <li>       Click the Incident ID to view your incidents<br></li>
            </ol>';
  body += 'If you need assistance, please call the Field Help Desk at 1-800-344-6776.<br>';
```

Comment: how are you setting this body.

Comment: What are the line break errors?

Comment: @All,  Thanks got it fine now but an unknown image comes in email body now. Can you guys let me know the reason? Please find the screenshot below.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is giving you error, as you are in fact breaking string

```
body += '<ol type="1">

     <li>       Log into the IREP app on your iPad and select...
```

Change it to:

```
body += '<ol type="1">';
body += '<li>       Log into the IREP app on your iPad and select ';
...
```

also please consider using workflow and/or email template for sending email (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved but getting an image stuff , can't figure out why. Can someone please look into this?

[image]

```
String body = 'Dear ' + OneMap.get(mycontact.ID).Rep_abv__r.Name + ', ';
  body += '<br><br>What you need to know: ';
  body += '<br>New ABS Incidents have been generated in iREP. Please review these incidents with your DM or Applicable Manager. There is no other action for you to complete in iREP.';
  body += '<br>To view your open incidents:<br>';
  body += '<ol type="1"><br><li>       Log into the iREP app on your iPad and select Compliance Incidents</li><br><li>       Select the Open Incidents. </li><br><li> View in the Compliance Incidents Home Page.</li><br><li>       Click the Incident ID to view your incidents.</li></ol> <br>If you need assistance, please call the Field Help Desk at 1-800-344-6776.<br>';
```